# Customer is not displaying Magento dashboard

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise

I have created a new customer using the API

```
http://{{doman_name}}/index.php/rest/V1/customers
```

When i can the login API, a token is returning .It means the customer is active.

```
http://{{doman_name}}/index.php/rest/V1/integration/customer/token
```

But the problem is,I can't see the customer in the admin dashboard.

[image]

Comment: Tried to reindex database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's the problem with indexing
if you are running linux server

```
go to magento root directory with root privileges 

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

For windows also same command works